# Looking for scalable NOSQL / NewSQL ( hybrid? ) DB for structured / unstructured Data compatible with .Net

Tags: json, database, nosql

I am wanting to write a very scalable Web Application with a database per "install" ( isolated instances ).

I want the power of relational databases in terms of table joins etc , but I want to give users the ability to create their own unstructured data within each table - and probably store as json / XML. One example of this would be product metadata.

What is out there in terms of a fast, scalable database. I've looked at
  - marklogic ( expensive )
  - SQL Server 2016 which seems to support jSon but I haven't installed 
  - bright star db
  - couch db 
  - I prefer .NET to access the data.

Anyway - I would like to be able to use it with as little custom connection for updating the custom data as possible , and I like using LINQ in the Entity framework.

The app would ultimately be able to scale up to millions of users - so I want to start with the end in mind.

What specific database would fit these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look into [Starcounter DBMS](http://starcounter.io) how well it fits your requirements.

Starcounter is integrated with .NET thus the database schema is defined through C# classes like in Entity Framework (EF). However, EF is Object Relational Mapper, while Starcounter works with .NET classes and their instances natively. All changes to data such as inserts and updates are done through C# objects manipulations. Since Starcounter hosts .NET applications, it provides ACID transactions for C# code directly, simplifying development of consistent applications.

Starcounter provides full stack for web development, simplifying development of scalable web applications and providing high performance and scalability. Starcounter implements MVVM pattern, where View Model is defined in JSON and bound to C# classes instances in the server code and data objects on client side.

Currently, Starcounter lacks LINQ driver, so SQL select statements have to be used for querying. Note that SQL is extended to allow operate data in object-oriented way: dot notation for references and returning objects instead of projecting primitive values.

Starcounter works efficiently with structured OO or relational data. It is necessary to carefully designed applications to work with unstructured data.